# document.form.submit() is too slow to complete before window.close()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit, race-condition

I am having an issue with saving a form. The form itself has about 40 rows with around 12 inputs for each row in this style:
[image: Sorting Rules Image]

On save, it should `POST` and then close the window. However, it never truly saves it. This makes me think that it is closing the window before it saves. Here's the code in question:

```
 $('#save-btn').click(function() {
    document.form.submit(); 
    window.close();
 };
```

If I remove the `window.close()` and use the inspector than I see in the parameters field that all the values save correctly. This is again what lead me to think that the window is closing to early.

I have tried using the following in the above `#save-btn` function:

```
setTimeout('window.close()',5000)
```

Yet this never seemed to execute the window.close() after the 5 seconds and all around seems like bad programming to force it to wait 5 seconds and then close when it could take any amount of time.

I then attempted to use an AJAX request like:

```
var _url = 'submit?nameParam="+nameParam+"&com=editlist&'+$('form').serialize();
console.log(_url); //just to see what its pushing out

$.ajax({
     url: _url,
     error: function(){
     alert('Error submitting form.');
     },

     success: function() {
     window.close();
     }
     });
```

This resulted in `414 Request-URI Too Long`. I know the case for this is it should be a `POST` to begin with, but I was just trying to make it work.

Just because, this is how our form is set up:

```
<form name="form" action="submit" method="post">
```

Our solution was to close the page from our action page

Comment: Your url is too long. That's not how POST works anyways. Just use the data property of the $.ajax config object.

Comment: POST would work that way, if closed from another page though.

Comment: Yes, by all means take all your form inputs, some of which may or may not run afoul of HIPAA or the GDPR or generally contain private or privileged info, and make them part of *public plaintext http request* that is also almost certainly logged in a plaintext/xml/json logfile on the server. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the serialized data from your _url and instead pass it through the .ajax() request with the `data` setting:

```
var _url = 'submit?nameParam="+nameParam+"&com=editlist';

$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    method: "POST",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    error: function() {
        alert('Error submitting form.');
    },
    success: function() {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked if I included method! 
How is that different from how I referenced the AJAX request from the original post? Would it have even worked if the URL was somehow shorter?

Comment: it uses "POST", your's was using "GET".

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax approach is correct because you can understand that form submit done correctly with code, on success post it is easy to close the window.

For sending a POST request, you have to make some small changes in your code...

- Don't serialize your form and add URL, it is not safe (not working for your situation).
- Post your values as "post data".

Here is documentation about it.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Please try and update your question if you cannot understand how.

Comment: I believe he was only serializing for his GET request.  I believe .ajax defaults to GET and his URL is too long for that.

Comment: Why wouldn't serialize be safe in this context?

Comment: It can generate long URL so can get 414. I mean the problem that you were hitting.